# Yii2 andSum() alternative

Tags: sql, yii2

I want to do something like this:

```
select id
from table1
group by id
having sum(feature = 10)
and sum(feature = 20)
```

There is my table

```
+----+---------+
| id | feature |
+----+---------+
| 1  |   10    |
| 1  |   20    |
| 2  |   20    |
| 3  |   40    |
| 4  |   50    |
| 5  |   60    |
+----+---------+
```

But using activeQuery. Unfortunelly, this haven't method "andSum()". What can I do?

Comment: how can be sum(feature = 10 ) and sum (feature = 20 ) can satisfy .. at the same time ...  ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
$data = modelName::find()->select(['id'])->groupBy('id')->having(['feature' => 10 , 'feature' => 20])->all();
```

**Note:** Not tested yet.

Comment: He is asking how to do it with `yii\db\ActiveQuery`, not with `yii\db\Query`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the query below will help , the "and" clause seems logically wrong

`select id , sum (feature ) as cond
from table1
group by id
having cond = 10 
or  cond = 20`

Edit after table definition you can do something like below

`select id 
  from table1 
  where id in (select id from  table1 where feature = 10 ) 
  and feature = 20`

Comment: I want to select id who have both features, no one of it.

Comment: @blablas can you put the table definition and sample of data table is having. I am unable to understand how a single attribute can have two value at same time , may be I am missing something

Comment: do u just want `having feature = 10 & feature = 20` or `sum(feature = 10)`.